# Making every other letter Capitalized

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a for loop to capitalize every other letter of a string. Here's what I've come up with so far..

```js
var input = "craig";
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = firstLetterUppercase();
function firstLetterUppercase () {
   for (i=0; i < input.length; i+=2) {
      input.charAt(i).toUpperCase;
      return input;  
   }
}
```

```html
<p id="para"> </p>
```

Why won't this work? Any Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by _every other letter_?

Comment: Take your `return` out of your loop. And `toUpperCase` is a function so you need to call it like `toUpperCase()`

Comment: 'cApItAlIzE' something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in javascript are immutable. You cannot modify original string. You'll have to create a new one:

```js
function firstLetterUppercase (input) {
  var res = "";
  for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
     res += i % 2 == 0 ? input.charAt(i).toUpperCase() : input.charAt(i);
  }
  return res;  
}

var test = 'test string';

console.log(firstLetterUppercase(test));
```

Answer (score 2):

`input.charAt()` wont modify the string in place, so you'll need to assign the result to something. There were also a few other problems, but here's something that rather resembles what you had, but works:

```js
function firstLetterUppercase (input) {
  for (i=0; i < input.length; i+=2) {
     input = input.substr(0, i) + input[i].toUpperCase() + input.substr(i + 1);
  }
  return input;  
}

var test = 'this is a test';

console.log(firstLetterUppercase(test));
```

Here's another version using a regex:

```js
var test = 'this is a test123';

function firstLetterUppercase() {
    return test.replace(/.{2}/g, function(match, $1, $2, offset, original) {
        return '' + match[0].toUpperCase() + match[1];
    })
}

console.log(firstLetterUppercase(test));
```

Answer (score 1):

- `return` keyword inside the `for` loop aborts it just right after the first cycle.
- `toUpperCase` is a function, you have to execute it on specified element, using `()`.
- `input.charAt(i).toUpperCase()` will return new changed letter, without mutating the original one.
- Instead of binding the whole function to the DOM element, bind just the returned variable.

I would suggest you to *split* the string or just use the *spread operator*, then *map* it using `Array#map` to change only letters with *even* index.

```js
var input = "craig",
    elem = document.getElementById("para");

function firstLetterUppercase() {
  elem.innerHTML = [...input].map((v,i) => i%2 ? v : v.toUpperCase()).join('');
}

firstLetterUppercase();
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```